# What exactly would need to be added to Bitcoin to support Zerocoin?

Tags: alternatives, zerocoin

I have read some information about Zerocoin, but not the actual paper.

My question is - what exactly would need to be added to Bitcoin full nodes in order to implement it?

Just the special "zerocoin mint" and "zerocoin spend" transactions? Are they some special, non-standard transactions?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that it's explained quite exactly here

https://github.com/Zerocoin/libzerocoin/wiki/Integrating-with-bitcoin-clients